# Distance Question - Shortest Possible Distance

Tags: calculus

Question: A straight line passing through the point $(8,27)$ intersects the positive x-axis at the point $P$ and the positive y-axis at the point $Q$. What is the shortest possible distance between $P$ and $Q$.

So from this
I concluded that $P = (x, 0)$ and $Q = (0, y)$
I made $R = (8, 27)$

I think I need to find the distance from $R$ to $P$ and $R$ to $Q$ and add them together to get the total, however, I don't understand how that would be the shortest possible distance. Also, when I tried doing this, I ended up with 2 variables.

Update: Everybody seems to be getting different results.... If it helps I'm in first year calculus and all we were given for this unit was the distance equation and how to find an equation from a tangent line and a point

Comment: Note that you can write $y$ as function of $x$. There is only one independent variable here.

Comment: I just tried that but I got x=y and I don't think that's the correct answer

Comment: let your answer determine on the slope of the line m

Comment: m=27/8??? cuz it passes through the origin??

Answer (score 2):

If the three points $P,Q,R$ are on a line, then for a suitable $t\in \mathbb R$ we have
$$ R = (1-t) P + t Q. $$
So you have 2 equations for 3 unknowns. Now, for example, solve $x$ and $y$ for $t$ and minimize 
$$ x^2(t) + y^2(t). $$

A different approach:

Say $m$ is the slope of the line going through $P,Q,R$. Then, we have
\begin{align*}
0 &= 27 + m(x - 8) \\
y &= 27 + m(0 - 8)
\end{align*}
Now, again, solve for $x$ and $y$ and minimize
$$ x^2(m) + y^2(m). $$

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand what you're saying. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @P.Layton do you know how 2 points define a line and how to parametrize that line?

Comment: I don't know what parametrize means.... >_<

Comment: @P.Layton that means you can describe each point on that line using a function.

Comment: No we were only given the distance equation and how to find the tangent line equation.

Answer (score 1):

My idea is to set the angle between $PQ$ and the $x$-axis as $\theta$. Hence, the length of $PQ$ is $$|PQ| = \frac{8}{\cos \theta}+\frac{27}{\sin\theta} :=f(\theta)\implies f'(\theta)=8\cdot\frac{\sin\theta}{\cos^2\theta}-27\cdot\frac{\cos\theta}{\sin^2\theta}$$
Solving the above equation for $f'(\theta )=0$, we know the derivative is $0$ when $\tan\theta = \frac{3}{2}$, and this gives the shortest distance because the boundary cases with $\theta\to 0^\circ$ and $\theta\to 90^\circ$ results in $|PQ|\to\infty$. Therefore, the shortest distance occurs when $$\cos\theta = \frac{2}{\sqrt{13}},\ \sin\theta = \frac{3}{\sqrt{13}} \implies |PQ|=13\sqrt{13}$$

Answer (score 1):

Your line should be of the form $y=m(x-8)+27$

Rewriting, we have $y=mx-8m+27$ or $\boxed{y=mx+(27-8m)}$ for y-intercept

Let's rewrite again $y-27=m(x-8)$ to $\frac{y}{m}-\frac{27}{m}+8=x$.

We have $\boxed{x=\frac{y}{m}+(8-\frac{27}{m})}$ for x-intercept.

Our y-intercept is $(0,27-8m)$ and our x-intercept is $(8-\frac{27}{m},0)$

Pythagorean theorem gives us the distance as $\sqrt{(27-8m)^2+(8-\frac{27}{m})^2}$.

Differentiate with respect to $m$ to get some nasty derivative, which is equal to zero at $m=\frac{3}{2}$.

The distance would be equal to $5\sqrt{13}$ units.

Comment: WAIT A MINUTE. IF THE SLOPE IS 27/8, THEN THE DISTANCE IS ZERO CUZ IT GOES THROUGH THE ORIGIN

Comment: So.......does that mean that the original method I used was correct? I got x=y and if you plug it into the distance equation I get 0

Comment: It should be $-\frac{3}{2}$ I guess

Comment: You can use a trigonometric approach to get a much simpler equation and much easier derivative :)

Comment: Ya, I thought so but I don't know how

Answer (score 1):

Oh dear.  Let's do this using only properties of derivatives, the usual point-slope equation of a line, and some algebra.

A line that passes through a point $R = (8,27)$ has the equation $$y - 27 = m(x-8),$$ for some slope $m$.  Thus the only variable that determines the points $P$ and $Q$ is the slope $m$.  The $x$-intercept is the value of $x$ when $y = 0$, so this is a function of $m$: $$P(m) = -\frac{27}{m} + 8.$$  Similarly, the $y$-intercept is the value of $y$ when $x = 0$:  $$Q(m) = -8m + 27.$$  It follows that the distance $PQ$ is a function of $m$ given by $$|PQ(m)| = \sqrt{P(m)^2 + Q(m)^2} = \sqrt{\frac{(27-8m)^2 (1+m^2)}{m^2}}.$$  Because distances are nonnegative, the distance is minimized when the squared distance is minimized; i.e., we can find the $m$ that minimizes $|PQ(m)|^2$ rather than $|PQ(m)|$.  To this end, we simply calculate the critical points:  $$0 = \frac{d}{dm}\left[|PQ(m)|^2 \right] = \frac{2}{m^3}(8m-27)(8m^3+27).$$  So $$m \in \left\{\frac{27}{8}, -\frac{3}{2}\right\}.$$  In the first case, the equation of the line passes through $(0,0)$:  this is not allowed, since we are told the $x$- and $y$-intercepts are positive.  Thus the only choice is $m = -3/2$, leading to the line $$y = -\frac{3}{2} x + 39,$$ and the minimum distance is $$|PQ(m)| = 13 \sqrt{13}.$$

[image]